# Java Image invert with "pure" color

Tags: java

I have one image with white background and black draw, and i want to reverse the  color of this image. (black background and white draw).

So I have make one method called "invertImage()". (above)
But i have a problem with the black color. I need "pure" black color. (000000).

But in my image i also have 010101 hexa black color, How can i add to my method a threshold to put all black color "pure" black (000000) ?

Thanks.

```
public static File invertImage(String imageName) {
    BufferedImage inputFile = null;
    try {
        inputFile = ImageIO.read(new File(imageName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < inputFile.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < inputFile.getHeight(); y++) {
            int rgba = inputFile.getRGB(x, y);
            Color col = new Color(rgba, true);
            col = new Color(255 - col.getRed(),255 - col.getGreen(),255 - col.getBlue());
            inputFile.setRGB(x, y, col.getRGB());
        }
    }

    try {
        File outputFile = new File(""+imageName+"");
        ImageIO.write(inputFile, "png", outputFile);
        return outputFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you also want "not pure whites" like fefefe to be turned into pure whites?

Comment: no, only black color :)

Comment: weird result : https://ibb.co/ffaD0b

Comment: Is this the resultant image? What's the image you gave it like?

Comment: Yes, this is the resultant. Original : https://ibb.co/k98SRG